# Responsive background (video background and background color)

Tags: html, css, video, background, background-color

I would like to know if it is possible to play a video background for screens (laptops 992px) and for smaller devices a black background without video.

I have already made an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/19r3q0st/1/) with a video background.

HTML code

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login/Logout animation concept</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
</head>

<body>
 <header class="video-header container">
  <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
    <video src="https://s3.envato.com/h264-video-previews/35654d71-df62-4468-9680-6c0bf9a95ff2/12292237.mp4" autoplay="true" muted="true" media="screen and (min-width:800px)">
    </video>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code

```
.video-header {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap video {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just use media queries and set different background for different screens.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: Hi Anna, Thanks for your response. I have seen an example about different background colors for different mediaqueries. Unfortunately I do not see an example to go from video to a solid background color. Can you give an example of how it should look like?

Comment: On certain size display none the video no set background to none and set background-color to black.